# 401 Authorization Required: Failed to validate oauth signature and token

Tags: perl, curl, twitter, oauth

I've tried using [Net::Twitter::Role::OAuth](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Twitter::Role::OAuth) to add [Sign in with Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in) to my application.

I've used this successfully in the past, but not with SSL enabled, which apparently is now required by the Twitter API. I have a controller action very similar to the examples in the synopsis:

```
sub twitter_authorize : Local {
    my($self, $c) = @_;

    my $nt = Net::Twitter->new(traits => [qw/API::RESTv1_1 OAuth/], %param);
    my $url = $nt->get_authorization_url(callback => $callbackurl);

    $c->response->cookies->{oauth} = {
        value => {
            token => $nt->request_token,
            token_secret => $nt->request_token_secret,
        },
    };

    $c->response->redirect($url);
}
```

However, this fails at the `$nt->get_authorization_url()` call with a 401 Unauthorized error.

Looking at the [oauth/request_token](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/post/oauth/request_token) docs, I tried running the request through cURL, as follows:

```
curl --request 'POST' 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token' --header 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="xxxx", oauth_nonce="xxxx", oauth_signature="xxxx", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="xxxx", oauth_callback="oob", oauth_version="1.0"' --verbose
```

And the response is as follows:

```
* About to connect() to api.twitter.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 199.16.156.104... 

connected
* Connected to api.twitter.com (199.16.156.104) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using AES128-SHA
* Server certificate:
*    subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=Twitter, Inc.; OU=Twitter Security; CN=api.twitter.com
*    start date: 2014-08-03 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: 2016-12-31 23:59:59 GMT
*    subjectAltName: api.twitter.com matched
*    issuer: C=US; O=VeriSign, Inc.; OU=VeriSign Trust Network; OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10; CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /oauth/request_token HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8k zlib/1.2.3.3 libidn/1.15
> Host: api.twitter.com
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="xxxx", oauth_nonce="xxxx", oauth_signature="xxxx", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="xxxx", oauth_callback="oob", oauth_version="1.0"
> 
< HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
< cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0
< content-length: 44
< content-security-policy-report-only: default-src https:; connect-src https:; font-src https: data:; frame-src https: http://*.twimg.com http://itunes.apple.com about: javascript:; img-src https: data:; media-src https:; object-src https:; script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' about: https:; style-src 'unsafe-inline' https:; report-uri https://twitter.com/i/csp_report?a=NVXW433SMFUWY%3D%3D%3D&ro=true;
< content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< date: Tue, 21 Oct 2014 10:29:57 UTC
< expires: Tue, 31 Mar 1981 05:00:00 GMT
< last-modified: Tue, 21 Oct 2014 10:29:57 GMT
< pragma: no-cache
< server: tsa_b
< set-cookie: _twitter_sess=BAh7CDoPY3JlYXRlZF9hdGwrCD2PQTJJAToHaWQiJTE3M2Q4OWIyZWE1Nzc1%250AZmYxMjRkYmUyZDVjOTBlYjQxIgpmbGFzaElDOidBY3Rpb25Db250cm9sbGVy%250AOjpGbGFzaDo6Rmxhc2hIYXNoewAGOgpAdXNlZHsA--b807e4ebb8d45756e9686971b951a549d0d83b61; domain=.twitter.com; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
< set-cookie: guest_id=v1%3A141388739758201626; Domain=.twitter.com; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 20-Oct-2016 10:29:57 UTC
< status: 401 Unauthorized
< strict-transport-security: max-age=631138519
< vary: Accept-Encoding
< x-connection-hash: 54a185631d5f0b3a3a9dc46fe1f40a57
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
< x-mid: 0258025664ce095129d0cc294100d71a2e6e66ac
< x-runtime: 0.01294
< x-transaction: 6fad295009a89877
< x-ua-compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1
< x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.twitter.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
Failed to validate oauth signature and token
```

Weirdly, if I remove the `oauth_callback` key from the Authorization header, it works fine and I get the tokens. However, the API docs suggest that this parameter is required. Is there something wrong with how I'm passing in the `oauth_callback` item?

I've tried setting it to `oob` (which is supposed to work for "out of band" access). And I've copied the encoded URL from the API docs. It doesn't work with either.

As it works without `oauth_callback`, it's not a time issue on my machine, as is a commonly reported problem. I haven't tried sending the Net::Twitter request without the callback (I haven't checked if that's possible) but I assume that would fix it there too. However, I do need the request to have a valid callback URL or the user won't be redirected back to the application for the rest of the sign in flow.

Answer (score 1):

Adam,

I was having a similar issue and after a thorough investigation of what other Twitter API wrapper libraries were doing discovered that the oauth_callback needed to be encoded twice.

On doing a retrospective? search to get a little more explanation/clarity I found the following SO answer [Twitter Oauth URL encoding inconsistencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283964/twitter-oauth-url-encoding-inconsistencies) which extremely succinctly explained the issue I was having.

Is this perhaps the issue you have encountered?

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I put the Twitter login on hold and worked on some other providers as I couldn't figure it out. I will go back to this soon and check the encoding.